# WordPress .htaccess preventing subfolder access

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite

This is sort of a goofy setup, but it's not in my power to reconfigure it at this time. I'm running in a shared hosting environment.

The domain is `example.com`. This is an add-on domain on the host side with `example.com` being redirected to the `www/example.com` sub-directory. That directory houses a standard WordPress site which acts as the main site when you visit `example.com`.

The *.htaccess* file within that directory is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/profile\.php$  /ssm/welcome [R] 
</IfModule>
```

I have a subdirectory, at the root level with the `/example.com` subdirectory that houses a CakePHP application. That subdirectory is `/tracker`.

My problem is that when I attempt to browse to `example.com/tracker`, I get a 404 from WordPress because permalinks are on. What I think I need is a rewrite rule in the WordPress *.htaccess* file that short circuits the existing rewrite rules and permits `example.com/tracker` to work independently of the WordPress install. Or a rewrite rule at the root level that short circuits the redirect to the `/example.com` directory in the first place.

Not sure how well I explained that so here's a summary.

The `www/` directory structure:

- `example.com/`
- `tracker/`

Add on domain of `www.example.com` redirecting to the `/example.com` directory with WordPress and a `tracker/` directory running CakePHP which I would like to access via `www.example.com/tracker`.

If you need further info or clarification let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a rewrite condition to prevent WordPress from taking over the URLs for tracker: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tracker/`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tracker/
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/profile\.php$  /ssm/welcome [R] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you are looking for but... You could simply create an add-on domain for your "tracker" application. It could be exactly the same in your `www/` directory, you gonna have the `example.com/` and the `tracker/` directory, the only difference is you gonna have to access the application with something like this : `http://tracker.example.com/`...

That could solve your problem as add-on domains are treated like independent websites inside of a domain. And i guess every shared hosting plan let you create an infinite amount of add-on domains for free :P

Comment: This is the current work around. Thanks for the suggestion!